# EntityFramework LINQ string order comparison

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

I have a `varchar(5)` column (named `name`) in my table (named `codes`). This SQL query is what I'd like to accomplish via EF, without first converting my `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` (in memory):

```
SELECT * FROM codes WHERE name >= 'J0000' AND name <= 'J9999'
```

I've tried performing a query using [this method](http://developers.de/blogs/andreas_lehmann/archive/2009/04/08/how-to-use-entity-framework-to-query-string-values-with-filter-conditions.aspx), like this:

```
var results = db.Codes.Where(c=>c.Name.CompareTo("J0000") >=0 
    &&  c.Name.CompareTo("J9999") <=0)
```

However the CompareTo can't be translated into sql and an exception is thrown. In order for CompareTo to work, you have to have an IEnumerable, meaning all the records are already pulled from the database into memory. When try to execute this I get:

```
{"The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."}
```

With stack trace:

```
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.NotSupportedTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.BinaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.BinaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
```

My only other option that I can think of is to use .SqlQuery() on my db.Codes DbSet in order to execute the actual select statement using >= and <=.

Are there any non-sql options that will allow me to perform a query like this?

**EDIT:** In my actual code I was doing a .CompareTo(codes[0]) where codes was an array of string. This array was breaking the EF sql translation. My solution was to get the string value into a new string variable first, and then pass the new string variable to .CompareTo() instead of the array variable / index specified.

Comment: can't you just do `c.Name >= "J0000'` in the linq instead of `CompareTo`?

Comment: @DLeh c.Name is a string. You can't compare strings that way in c#. Also it needs to be translatable to sql by the EF innards.

Comment: my mistake, i was thinking of javascript i guess.

Comment: Why can't `CompareTo` be used? It works for me.

Comment: @DavidG Really? When you trace out the sql query has it been converted to WHERE name >= '..." ?

Comment: Just tried it out and my SQL looks like this `WHERE [Extent1].[columnname] > N'mytext'`

Comment: That error doesn't seem to match the code you posted. Is that the EXACT code in your project?

Comment: You're right. I had .CompareTo(codes[0]) where codes was a string array. I would have thought that codes[0] would be evaluated before the sql translation, but it doesn't. Grabbing the string into a new var on a previous line and then using it instead fixed the problem!

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer already to reflect that :)

Comment: Thank you so much @DavidG for helping me think through this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkw3h78a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to compare your strings. Entity Framework converts these into `>`, `<`, `>=` and `<=`.

```
var results = db.Codes.Where(c => c.Name.CompareTo("J0000") >= 0);
```

Or using this syntax:

```
var results = from c in db.Codes
              where c.Name.CompareTo("J0000") >= 0
              select c;
```

This will produce SQL output similar to this:

```
WHERE [Extent1].[Name] >= N'J0000'
```

**EDIT**

After you gave your error message it seems you are using an indexed property instead of string literals in your Linq query. To fix this, copy the values to temporary variables. So this:

```
var results = db.Codes.Where(c=>    c.Name.CompareTo(somearray[0]) >=0 
                                 && c.Name.CompareTo(somearray[1]) <=0)
```

Becomes this:

```
var lowerBound = somearray[0];
var upperBound = somearray[1];

var results = db.Codes.Where(c=>    c.Name.CompareTo(lowerBound) >=0 
                                 && c.Name.CompareTo(upperBound) <=0)
```